# Convert a ValidationNel[A, List[B]] into ValidationNel[A, NonEmptyList[B]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have written a combinator to convert a `ValidationNel[A, List[B]]` into `ValidationNel[A, NonEmptyList[B]]` that returns a `Failure` when the `List` is empty.

```
  def nonEmpty[A, B](valid : ValidationNel[A, List[B]], fail : => A) : ValidationNel[A, NonEmptyList[B]] =
    valid match {
      case Failure(f) => f.failure[NonEmptyList[B]]
      case Success(s) =>
        if (!s.isEmpty) NonEmptyList(s.head, s.tail:_*).successNel[A]
        else fail.failureNel[NonEmptyList[B]]
    }
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can improve your `nonEmpty` function in two ways :

- Scalaz can turn a `List` into an `Option[NonEmptyList]` using
  `toNel`.
- Your pattern match on `ValidationNel` is similar to a `flatMap`, but `Validation` doesn't have a `flatMap` operation since it is an *Applicative* and not a *Monad*. Scalaz provides some easy functions to convert between `Validation` and `\/` (also known as disjunction), so we can use `\/`'s `flatMap`.

Your `nonEmpty` function then could look like :

```
import scalaz.{ValidationNel, NonEmptyList}
import scalaz.syntax.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.nel._

def nonEmpty[A, B](valid: ValidationNel[A, List[B]], 
                   fail: => A): ValidationNel[A, NonEmptyList[B]] =
  valid.disjunction.flatMap(_.toNel toRightDisjunction fail.wrapNel).validation
```

Which you could use as :

```
import scalaz.syntax.validation._

nonEmpty(List(1,2).success, "test")
// scalaz.ValidationNel[String,scalaz.NonEmptyList[Int]] = 
//   Success(NonEmptyList(1, 2))

nonEmpty(List().success, "list is empty")
// scalaz.ValidationNel[String,scalaz.NonEmptyList[Nothing]] =
//   Failure(NonEmptyList(list is empty))
```

Comment: From which implicit the `wrapNel` comes from ? I have this compilation error : `value wrapNel is not a member of type parameter A`

Comment: `scalaz.syntax.nel._`

Comment: got it. It seems that there was a conflict with this import `scalaz.syntax.all._`